# How to Extend RemoteAttribute to make Entry to the ModelState?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

MODEL

```
[Remote("ValidateDuplicateUsername", "Account", ErrorMessage = "Username is already taken")]
public string Username { get; set; }
```

CONTROLLER

```
ModelState.IsValid
```

The `RequiredAttribute` automatically adds entry to `ModelState` if the field is invalid.
And then it displays the error message in the view.

How can I also do that using the `RemoteAttribute`? so that when I call the ModelState.IsValid, it also validates the Remote Validation?

Answer (score 0):

> The RequiredAttribute automatically adds entry to ModelState if the field is invalid

No, you must have misunderstood something. The Required attribute doesn't add anything to the ModelState. Validation attributes do not have access to ModelState neither to HttpContext. They override the IsValid method and return true or false to indicate whether the model is valid or not. It is the default model binder that executes validation when trying to bind the model from the request that adds errors to ModelState. Data Annotations are designed to be MVC independent. They are in a separate assembly (System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations) with the idea of using them for example in WPF, Silverlight, ... applications. So you understand that the notion of ModelState doesn't make sense.

So if you look at the IsValid implementation of the RemoteAttribute you will notice the following:

```
public override bool IsValid(object value)
{
    return true;
}
```

That's the reason why the RemoteAttribute considers your model as valid when you post the form. You could write your custom remote validation attribute and override this method.

Comment: "...Data Annotations are designed to be MVC independent..." Why resides the RemoteAttribute then in the System.Web.Mvc namespace ? In WPF you do not use this kind of attributes. There is IDataErrorInfo for this. Better stick to asp.net mvc Darin ;-)

Comment: The Remote attribute is a specific ASP.NET MVC validation attribute: it uses client side javascript which has no meaning in other applications such as WPF.

Comment: ok because you wrote that in your soluton above hehe. Btw. you are a qicker answerer :P